# service Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console-application

I am having a strange issue. If i start my console application exe, it's working fine and processing records.

If  I tried to start as service, it's ending up with Error 1053.

Anybody had this issue before, how to resolve it??

Comment: Can you provide code so the problem can be distinguished?

Comment: `tried to start as service` How exactly did you do that?